# How to get XElement.ToString() to omit the space before the self-closing slash?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, xelement

By default, a self-closing tag is `ToString()`ed by `XElement` as follows:

```
<element />

<element attrib="value" />
```

However, I would like it without the extra space, i.e.

```
<element/>

<element attrib="value"/>
```

Is this possible with the `XElement` API?

Comment: you can do a string replace that will replace " />" with "/>"

Comment: Doing a fun system integration are you? Sometimes I find myself thinking there should be a public list somewhere, along the lines of http://plaintextoffenders.com/ , for systems that don't accept valid xml when it's not **their kind** of valid xml :)

Comment: @AakashM: Such a site might be fun, but in my case that wasn’t the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I’ll just do a string replace that will replace `" />"` with `"/>"`.

Comment: If you want to keep the functional style of syntax, you can add an extension method to XElement called something like ToStringNoSpace() which calls the XElement.ToString() and does the replace as well.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin: `.Replace(" />", "/>")` is perfectly functional style.